# Numpy 4d array slicing

Tags: python, numpy

Why does slicing a 4d array give me a 3d array? I expected a 4d array with extent 1 in one of the dimensions.

Example:

```
print X.shape
(1783, 1, 96, 96)
```

Slice array:

```
print X[11,:,:,:].shape
```

or

```
print X[11,:].shape
```

gives me `(1, 96, 96)`, but I expected `(1, 1, 96, 96)`

I can do it by `print X[11:12,:].shape`, but I wonder why the first method doesn't work as I expect?

Comment: Or you can say `X[ [11], : ].shape`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> An integer, `i`, returns the same values as `i:i+1` **except** the dimensionality of the returned object is reduced by `1`. In particular, a selection tuple with the `p`-th element an integer (and all other entries `:`) returns the corresponding sub-array with dimension `N - 1`. If `N = 1` then the returned object is an array scalar.

---

Thus, when your index is an integer, the value(s) at that index is(are) returned and the corresponding axis is removed. In one dimension the behavior is as you would expect:

```
In [6]: a = np.arange(5); a
Out[6]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [7]: a[2]
Out[7]: 2

In [8]: a[2].shape
Out[8]: ()
```

`a` is 1-dimensional, `a[2]` is 0-dimensional.

In higher dimensions, if `X` is 4-dimensional and of shape `(1783,1,96,96)`, then
`X[11,:,:,:]` returns all the values where the first axis index equals 11 and then that axis is removed. So `X[11,:,:,:].shape` is `(1,96,96)`.

When the slice specifies a range, such as `a[2:3]` then all the values within that range are returned and the axis is not removed:

```
In [9]: a[2:3]
Out[9]: array([2])

In [10]: a[2:3].shape
Out[10]: (1,)
```

Similarly, `X[11:12, :, :, :]` has shape `(1,1,96,96)`.